# Passing an associative array as value for a checkbox form (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session, checkbox

I'm a new member on this site, though I've used it plenty before. I searched a bit for an answer to my question, but I can't seem to find one. So I figured I'll post on here.

Anyway, on to the question. In my code, what I want to do is create an associative array, and then somehow pass that value through $_POST. My most recent idea is to create the associative array, then use json_encode to a string, pass that string as the value for a checkbox and then, get the string value through $_POST and use json_decode to get that associative array.

So say I have an associate array called $array. I would encode it like so:

```
$string = json_encode($array)
```

Then I pass the string as the value for the checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='array[]' value='$string'>
```

Then, once the form is submitted, it gets the associatives array(s) and updates some $_SESSION values:

```
foreach ($_POST['array'] as $element)
{
    $array = json_decode($element,true);
    array_push($_SESSION['array'], $array);
    $_SESSION['sum'] = $_SESSION['sum'] + $array["price"];
}
```

However, I get a fatal error everytime this runs, something along the lines of "Unsupported operand types" referring to the line with $_SESSION['sum']. I also get an error whenever I try to see values of the array as well (e.g. echo $array["price"] or echo $array["size"]), with those errors being "Array to string conversion".

Anyone have any ideas? I'm pretty new to PHP (just started learning it this week, if you couldn't tell)

Comment: It seems like this should work. If you use View Source, do you see the JSON in the `value` attribute?

Comment: Try echoing out $_POST['array'] before you enter the loop. That might be what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the checkbox rendering:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='array[]' value="<?php echo $string; ?>">
```

Comment: Added that and the code runs, but unfortunately it doesn't update $_SESSION variables (e.g. doesn't update $_SESSION['sum']). No more errors though which is nice, thanks!

Comment: Add session_start(); at the begining of the script

Comment: I have session_start() at the top of all of my php files, including in update.php which is where SESSION is updated. However, I do redirect back to index.php by using the header method after the script in update.php runs, so maybe that is causing the funky behavior?

Comment: Tried that and still nothing. But I think I'm on the right path. Thanks for your help so far!